# install.packages() in R

Tags: r, install.packages

I am trying to install an R package from its source file. The package could be installed only on R.2.9.2. So I uninstall my new version of R, installed the mentioned version and tried to install package like this:

```
 install.packages(pathToPackage, repos="NULL", type="source")
```

But I am receiving this error:

```
  argument 'lib' is missing: using 'C:\Users\hora\Documents/R/win-library/2.9'
Warning: unable to access index for repository NULL/src/contrib
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘c://Users//hora//Downloads//affymicro.zip’ is not available
```

What is the solution? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like the path is incorrect. Could you write the first argument explicitly? Also, I don't think you need quotes around NULL.

Comment: @Maxim.K This is the whole command. I also deleted the the quotes. >  install.packages("c://Users//hora//Downloads//affymicro.zip", repos=NULL, type="source")

Comment: Did the output change without the quotes?

Comment: @Maxim.K I have the path in the wrong way I guess now the error is like below: install.packages("C:\\Users\\hora\\Downloads\\affymicro.zip", repos=NULL, type="source")
Warning in install.packages("C:\\Users\\hora\\Downloads\\affymicro.zip",  :
  argument 'lib' is missing: using 'C:\Users\hora\Documents/R/win-library/2.9'
'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning message:
In install.packages("C:\\Users\\hora\\Downloads\\affymicro.zip",  :
  installation of package 'C:/Users/hora/Downloads/affymicro.zip' had non-zero exit status

Comment: Maybe just build the package from source outside of R and then see if you can load it into your current (newer) version?

Comment: Perhaps you can solve this by installing the dependencies like affymicro up front from official R mirrors, and only then installing the package in question from its file.